# How to get the employees with their managers in a Report Format

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me to resolve the following issues please?

## Issues:

```
I need a SQL Server Query to generate a Report listing the Employees in their order of Job Profile Hierarchy
```

-

```
The CTE Query generates a wrong output in the first record with Manager Name and Job Profile where MgrID is NULL
```

The Sample Data is:

## Query:

```
Select * From MyEmp;
```

## Result:

```
EmpNo   EmpName JobProfile  DeptNo  MgrID   LevelID
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   10      NULL    01
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     30      7839    02
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     10      7839    02
7566    JONES   MANAGER     20      7839    02
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    30      7698    03
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    30      7698    03
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    30      7698    03
7900    JAMES   CLERK       30      7698    03
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    30      7698    03
7902    FORD    ANALYST     20      7566    03
7369    SMITH   CLERK       20      7902    04
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     20      7566    03
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       20      7788    04
7934    MILLER  CLERK       10      7782    03
```

The CTE Query is:

## CTE Query:

```
WITH Subordinates AS
(
  (SELECT   e.EmpNo, e.EmpName, e.JobProfile, e.LevelID, e.MgrID,
            m.EmpName MgrName, m.JobProfile MgrProfile
   FROM MyEmp AS e
   INNER JOIN
        MyEmp AS m ON
            e.MgrID is NULL
            AND m.MgrID is NULL)
    UNION ALL
 (SELECT    e.EmpNo, e.EmpName, e.JobProfile, e.LevelID, e.MgrID,
            sub.EmpName MgrName, sub.JobProfile MgrProfile
   FROM MyEmp AS e 
   INNER JOIN 
        Subordinates AS sub ON 
            e.MgrID = sub.EmpNo
    )
)
SELECT * FROM Subordinates AS s;
```

## Result:

```
EmpNo   EmpName JobProfile  LevelID MgrID   MgrName MgrProfile
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   01      NULL    KING    PRESIDENT
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     02      7839    KING    PRESIDENT
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     02      7839    KING    PRESIDENT
7566    JONES   MANAGER     02      7839    KING    PRESIDENT
7902    FORD    ANALYST     03      7566    JONES   MANAGER
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     03      7566    JONES   MANAGER
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       04      7788    SCOTT   ANALYST
7369    SMITH   CLERK       04      7902    FORD    ANALYST
7934    MILLER  CLERK       03      7782    CLARK   MANAGER
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    03      7698    BLAKE   MANAGER
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    03      7698    BLAKE   MANAGER
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    03      7698    BLAKE   MANAGER
7900    JAMES   CLERK       03      7698    BLAKE   MANAGER
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    03      7698    BLAKE   MANAGER
```

The Oracle Query with `CONNECT BY ... PRIOR TO` is capable of resolving this problem, but I need a Query that can be effective on a SQL Server

## Oracle Query

```
Select e.MgrID,
        --m.EmpName MgrName, m.JobProfile MgrProfile, 
        e.EmpNo, e.EmpName, e.JobProfile
   FROM MyEmp AS e 
  -- LEFT OUTER JOIN
  --        MyEmp AS m ON
  --        e.MgrID is NULL
        --AND m.MgrID is NULL
    START WITH e.MgrID is NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR EmpNo = MgrID
    ;
```

Comment: What does this mean:   "in their order of Job Profile Hierarchy"?    Please post an example of the results you are trying to get.

Comment: Hi Tab,  I mean the list should be in the order of employees reporting under their higher-ups.  eg. *Manager > Analyst (working under this particular Manager ...)  This is possible in Oracle with the query mentioned above.  Please Help.  Thanks.  JDB.

Comment: That answer is not sufficient.   I would need to see an example of desired results in order to help.

Comment: Kindly send me your email id and I'll try to send you the screen shot of the result I'm looking for. TIA.

Comment: If you post the screenshot to imgur and add a link to it in your question, I will edit your question to include it, and hopefully be able to assist further.